How to handle NA (unavailable data) while importing from CSV files?
I decided to create a local database using Duckdb, but wasn't able to resolve a problem related to import of data from CSV files. A reason for that are NAs that is a quite frequent issue in social sciences. For instance, columns of CSV files that may at first be detected as 'INTEGER', may contain NAs that later prevents from importing such data into the database.
I tried to find a solution online, be wasn't successfull. My expectation that there would be an elegant and general solution available online didn't occur. Since I don't have enough experience in SQL and DuckDB, I haven't been able to come up with a solution myself.
So, it would be great support to my work if the community could share thoughts/experience related to the issue and how to overcome it to move on?
Thank you.

What do you mean by NA exactly? Can you show an example? i.e. are you saying you have 1\n2\nNA\n4 and that gets read as a varchar column instead of integer?

Generally speaking, yes. I have a column with numbers (data type INTEGER) that also contains NA (data type "VARCHAR"), and while importing it is not possible to identify which type to use. I don't think that VARCHAR would be suitable for numeric data  though.

So the literal value NA? You can specify custom null string values e.g. read_csv(file, nullstr=['NA']) - is this what you're looking for?
